# encrypt streaming until public ip

Tags: linux, linux-mint, streaming

i want to create a web radio station in linux (mint or whatever) with icecast2 and darkice.
my concept is to have a server A in a place who will running the darkice and at server A will recording the mic, 
and then the darkice will send the data to a server B that B will be far away and from that place-IP the people will connect and listen to the streaming

my question is can somebody see the data that travel between the server A (private mystic unsafe ip- darkice-radio station) and the server B(public safe IP)

so,in other words i want to set up a web radio in a place A (A external IP), and to give it to the public with another IP (server B)

excuse me for bad english 
thnx!

Comment: based on your explanation that you gonna use external IP for server `A` which is static ip, and a public ip for server `B` gonna be given for back end client in order to stream ? so kindly confirm which data transportation you gonna use in order to allow us to help you?

Answer (score 1):

To put it simple, if you are using a non-encrypted protocol such as HTTP, FTP, RTSP. Then yes, in that sutation it would be a typical man-in-the-middle attack.

And the way to overcome your concern is quit simple in Linux.

What you have to do is:

1. Establish a secure shell connection (SSH) with port forwarding.
2. Continuously check the connectivity and re-establish upon disconnection.

To establish a connection use the following command:

```
~$ ssh username@serverIP -D 9999
```

A good reference:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding

Comment: A VPN connection may work better, as it would auto-reconnect.

Comment: @JasonRush Ya I agree, but that's an added complexity to set-up an VPN server. Also if the connection between the two point is reliable, we should not consider network loss or disconnection.

Comment: Over the years I've learned not to assume perfect reliability, and (split-tunnel) VPN would also be one less manual step for someone to remember.